# How to make my PC always ask for operating system

Tags: linux, windows-10

I have three partitions in my drive:

1. (C)
2. (F)
3. (E)

First, I had installed Windows in partition `C:` then I installed Linux in partition `E:`. During that time everything was good and my PC was always asking for the operating system on startup, but after that for some reason I had to reinstall Windows. I just format partition `C:` and reinstalled Windows in that drive again but now I have a problem. My PC is not asking for an operating system on startup, it just always starts Windows.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: When you reinstalled Windows it overwrote your boot sector.  You can boot a Linux LiveCD/USB, use `chroot` to get into your linux system, and re-install GRUB.

Comment: sorry to say but didn't get a single thing can you please define briefly :( @ivanivan

Comment: When you installed Windows it made a change to the boot sector of the drive. You need to boot Linux (eg using a USB drive) and rebuild this boot sector. The software which you are most likely using to multiboot is called GRUB.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows